# Ambiguous type variables with Haskell functional dependencies

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I was playing around with the FunctionalDependencies-Extension of Haskell, along with MultiParamTypeClasses. I defined the following:

```
class Add a b c | a b -> c where
    (~+) :: a -> b -> c
    (~-) :: a -> b -> c
    neg :: a -> a
    zero :: a
```

which works fine (I've tried with instances for Int and Double with the ultimate goal of being able to add Int and Doubles without explicit conversion).

When I try to define default implementations for neg or (~-) like so:

```
class Add ...
    ...
    neg n = zero ~- n
```

GHCi (7.0.4) tells me the following:

```
Ambiguous type variables `a0', `b0', `c0' in the constraint:
  (Add a0 b0 c0) arising from a use of `zero'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `(~-)', namely `zero'
In the expression: zero ~- n
In an equation for `neg': neg n = zero ~- n

Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (Add a0 a a) arising from a use of `~-'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: zero ~- n
In an equation for `neg': neg n = zero ~- n
```

I think I do understand the problem here. GHC does not know *which* zero to use, since it could be any zero yielding anything which in turn is fed into a `~-` which we only know of, that it has an `a` in it's right argument and yields an `a`.

So how can I specify that it should be the zero from the very same instance, i.e. how can I express something like:

```
neg n = (zero :: Add a b c) ~- n
```

I think the `a`, `b` and `c` here are *not* the a b c form the surrounding class, but any a b and c, so how can I express a type which is a reference to the local type variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pull `neg` and `zero` out into a superclass that only uses the one type:

```
class Zero a where
    neg :: a -> a
    zero :: a

class Zero a => Add a b c | a b -> c where
    (~+) :: a -> b -> c
    (~-) :: a -> b -> c
```

The point is that your way, `zero :: Int` could be the `zero` from `Add Int Int Int`, *or* the `zero` from `Add Int Double Double`, and there is no way to disambiguate between the two, regardless of whether you're referring to it from inside a default implementation or an instance declaration or normal code.

(You may object that the `zero` from `Add Int Int Int` and the `zero` from `Add Int Double Double` will have the same value, but the compiler can't know that someone isn't going to define `Add Int Char Bool` in a different module and give `zero` a different value there.)

By splitting the typeclass into two, we remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot express the `zero` function as part of the `Add` class. All type variables in the class declaration must be encountered in the type declaration for each function of the class; otherwise, Haskell won't be able to decide which type instance to use because it is given too few constraints.

In other words, `zero` is not a property of the class you are modelling. You are basically saying: "For any three types `a`, `b`, `c`, there must exist a zero value for the type `a`", which makes no sense; you could pick any `b` and `c` and it would solve the problem, hence `b` and `c` are completely unusable, so if you have an `Add Int Int Int` or an `Add Int (Maybe String) Boat`, Haskell does not know which instance to prefer. You need to separate the property of negation and "zeroness" into a separate class(es) of types:

```
class Invertible a where
  invert :: a -> a

neg :: Invertible a => a -> a
neg = invert

class Zero a where
  zero :: a

class Add a b c | a b -> c where
  (~+) :: a -> b -> c
  (~-) :: a -> b -> c
```

I don't see why you would then even need the `Invertible` and `Zero` constraints in `Add`; you can always add numbers without knowing their zero value, can you not? Why express `neg` as a requirement for `~+`; there are some numbers that should be addable without them being negatable (Natural numbers for instance)? Just keep the class concerns separate.